# how to manipulate the txt file using C++ STL HOmework

Tags: c++, stl

I have a txt file that contains name, id number, mobilenumber, and location in comma separated line.
example 
 Robby, 7890,7788992356, 123 westminister 
 tom, 8820, 77882345, 124 kingston road
My task is to retrieve

Look up all of an employee's information by name.
Look up all of an employee's information by ID.
Add the information of an employee.
Update the information of an employee.

SO far I have  read the file and stored the information in a vector. Code is shown below. 
For tasks
1)Look up all of an employee's information by name.  I will iterate in the  vector  and prints information containing the name . I will be able to do that
2) simialry in text file I will look for id and prints information  about that.
BUT I am clueless about point 3 & 4.

I am posting my code below

```
void filter_text( vector<string> *words, string name)    
{    
 vector<string>::iterator startIt = words->begin();    
 vector<string>::iterator endIt = words->end();    
 if( !name.size() )        
     std::cout << " no word to found for empty string ";  

 while( startIt != endIt)     
 {      
    string::size_type pos = 0;     
    while( (pos = (*startIt).find_first_of(name, pos) ) !=  string::npos)    
        std:cout <<" the name is " << *startIt<< end;    
    startIt++;     
 }
}     

int main()               
{             
 // to read a text file       
  std::string file_name;   
  std::cout << " please enter the file name to parse" ;    
  std::cin  >> file_name;

  //open text file for input
  ifstream infile(file_name.c_str(), ios::in) ;
  if(! infile)
  {
    std::cerr <<" failed to open file\n";
    exit(-1);
  }
 vector<string> *lines_of_text = new vector<string>;
 string textline;
 while(getline(infile, textline, '\n'))
 {
    std::cout <<" line text:" << textline <<std::endl;
    lines_of_text->push_back(textline);
 }
filter_text( lines_of_text, "tony");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of incomplete sentences and ideas here.

Comment: How about tokenizing each line (splitting at the comma) and storing the result in a `std::map<int, other_data>`?

Comment: If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: I was going to suggest a `vector` of `struct`s.  It's a smaller step from what he's got now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

struct bird {
    std::string name;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

bird& find_bird_by_name(std::vector<bird>& birds, const std::string& name) {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<birds.size(); ++i) {
        if (birds[i].name == name)
            return birds[i];
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("BIRD NOT FOUND");
}

bird& find_bird_by_weight(std::vector<bird>& birds, int weight) {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<birds.size(); ++i) {
        if (birds[i].weight< weight)
            return birds[i];
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("BIRD NOT FOUND");
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("birds.txt");
    char comma;
    bird newbird;
    std::vector<bird> birds;
    //load in all the birds
    while (infile >> newbird.name >> comma >> newbird.weight >> comma >> newbird.height)
        birds.push_back(newbird);
    //find bird by name
    bird& namebird = find_bird_by_name(birds, "Crow");
    std::cout << "found " << namebird.name << '\n';
    //find bird by weight
    bird& weightbird = find_bird_by_weight(birds, 10);
    std::cout << "found " << weightbird.name << '\n';
    //add a bird
    std::cout << "Bird name: ";
    std::cin >> newbird.name;
    std::cout << "Bird weight: ";
    std::cin >> newbird.weight;
    std::cout << "Bird height: ";
    std::cin >> newbird.height;
    birds.push_back(newbird);
    //update a bird
    bird& editbird = find_bird_by_name(birds, "Raven");
    editbird.weight = 1000000;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously not employees, because that would make your homework too easy.

Comment: Thanks Duck for helping me . BUt I am just wondering will function find_bird_by_name will work in case i have multiple entries of same name and i want to retrieve all the info of same name

Comment: Mope, I coded it to find only the first match.  To return multiple, it will have to create a `std::vector<bird>` and `push_back` all the `bird`s that match, and then return that `vector`.

Comment: Thanks Mooing, I have fix the issue.  Many thanks to everyone  for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting the CSV line into separate fields and then populate a struct with this data

eg:

```
struct Employee
{
    std::string name;
    std::string id_number;
    std::string mobilenumber;
    std::string location;
};

std::vector<Employee> employees; // Note you dont need a pointer
```

Look at string methods find_first_of, substr and friends.

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, I don't think you should store the information in a vector of strings. This kind of task totally calls for the use of a

```
struct employee {
   int id;
   std::string name;
   std::string address;
   //... more info
};
```

And storing instances of employees in an

```
 std::vector<employee>
```

You see, using your strategy of storing the lines, searching for "westminster" would net me Robbie, as his line of text does include this substring, but his name isn't westminster at all. Storing the data in a vector of employee structs would eliminate this problem, and it'd make the whole thing a lot more, well, structured.

Of course you'd need to actually parse the file to get the info into the vector. I'd suggest using a strategy like:

```
while(getline(infile, textline, '\n')) {
    std::stringstream l(textline);
    getline(l,oneEmp.name, ','); //extract his name using getline
    l >> oneEmp.id;  //extract his id
    //extract other fields from the stringstream as neccessary
    employees.push_back(oneEmp);
}
```

As for adding information: when the user enters the data, just store it in your employees vector; and when you should need to update the file, you may simply overwrite the original data file with a new one by opening it for writing & dumping the data there (this is obviously a rather wasteful strategy, but it's fine for a school assignment (I suppose it's school assignment)).